# Python : read and print sequence from a fasta file

Tags: python, fasta

I am trying to print only the sequence id, not the entire description line, in the input file along with the GC content next to it from a fasta file, such as:

```
Seq1   40%
Seq2   37%
Seq3   12%
```

When I run this code nothing occurs.

```python
def main():
    calcGC()

def calcGC():
    fileReader = open("Sequences.fasta",'r')
    for line in fileReader:
        seqID = line.startswith (">")
        seq = line[0:]

    gc_count = float((seq.count("G") + seq.count("C"))) / len(seq)*100
    print(seqID+"   "+ gc_count)

    fileReader.close

main()
```

Comment: There is a problem with indentation in your sample code I believe ?

Comment: For contributors who are not acquainted with your specific problem, could you please mention, in your question, what output do you expect when you run this code?

Comment: The output I expect is in columns:                                               Seq1     23%                                                           Seq2     26%

Answer (score 0):

This will print something, not the output you want. There are several errors in your code:

The indentation is wrong.

`SeqID` is a boolean that only checks if the line starts with `<` character. So I would guess you want that to test if you should print the line or not. Anyway, if what you want to print is the line number if it starts with `<` it would be something like this:

```
def calcGC():
    fileReader = open("Sequences.fasta", 'r')
    for seqID, line in enumerate(fileReader):
        if line.startswith(">"):
            seq = line[0:]

            gc_count = float((seq.count("G") + seq.count("C"))) / len(seq) * 100
            print(seqID, "   ", gc_count)

    fileReader.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    calcGC()
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing I can see here is a problem of scope. 
You call line, in a lobal scope but line is accessible only in a loop of your calcGC function scope. In python, scope is defined by identation.

Now the second thing i see here and i do not understand is the use of `.startswith()` method. It will return a Bollean, not the seqID...maybe add an if statement here ?

Another last thing is : you should use the `with` statement for openning a file, it will close the file for you and give you a generator.
By the way, the line : `seq = line[0:]` is not required here, you can use "seq" directly in the loop, like so :

```
def main():
    calcGC()

def calcGC():
    with open("Sequences.fasta", 'r') as fp :
        # using the enumerate here will give you both the index and the line itself. I assume here that the seqID you wanted to use is the Line index....
        for seqID, seq in enumerate(fp):
            if seq.startswith(">"):
                gc_count = float((seq.count("G") + seq.count("C"))) / len(seq) * 100
                print("{} {}".format(seqID,gc_count))


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it seems that people here aren't familiar with the .fasta format. [(Wikipedia article)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format)
The header/seq_ID/info line starts always with the ">" character followed by whatever info the author put there, hence checking if line starts with ">".

So if

```
if line.startswith(">"):
```

is True, then we are in the header line. To get the header, you would use

```
seq_ID = line[1:] # not line[0:], as we don't need the ">"
```

All the following lines are then the sequence data belonging to that header, until the next line starting with ">" comes or the file ends.

Once you have collected all the sequence data (following a header), you then calculate the GC content of the **sequence data**, **not the header!!** (as the question and both answers do it the other way, which biologically is not meaningful)

If you can, just use the biopython package:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.SeqUtils import GC

input_file = "Sequences.fasta"

for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(input_file, "fasta"):
    print(f'{seq_record.id} {round(GC(seq_record.seq))}%')
```

(Code is just slightly adapted from [biopython tutorial](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#sec63))